# How to implement validation on 2 dependent fields?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Hi everyone iam writing post api in spring boot and i need to implement this validation
i have 2 fields - order type and additional details, order type is enum class which consists of 2 enum's - a and b , suppose if "a" is given as input it will proceed as it is - no validation required, suppose if it's "b" then additional details field must required, this is my requirement --- this is a post call

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve that.

Firstly, javax.validation.constraints package has an `@AssertTrue` annotation, using which you can define a method in your class with some validation logic, e.g. like this:

```
@AssertTrue(message = "secondField must not be null if firstField is B")
public boolean isValid() {
    return SomeEnum.A.equals(firstField) || secondField != null;
}
```

Secondly, you can define your own validation annotation - similar to how annotations are implemented in validation package - and a validator that implements `ConstraintValidator`. E.g. like this:

```
@ValidMyObject
public class MyObject {
    private SomeEnum firstField;
    private Object secondField;
    // getters, setters, etc.
}

@Target({TYPE,ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyObjectValidator.class)
public @interface ValidMyObject {
    String message() default "secondField must not be null if firstField is B";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

@Component
public class MyObjectValidator
  implements ConstraintValidator<ValidMyObject, MyObject> {
    
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MyObject obj, ConstraintValidatorContext context){
        return SomeEnum.A.equals(obj.getFirstField()) || obj.getSecondField != null;
    }
}
```

Note that the `@Target` annotation defines that this annotation can be used at a TYPE level - on a class, to perform the validation of the entire MyObject object.

Take a look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-constraints) for details.

P.S. Don't forget about dependencies for validation implementation: for spring-boot the most popular one is 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'.